# jsp files not working on subdomain

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, subdomain

I have created new subdomain http://abc.example.com successfully. But jsp files not working, I mean java is not loaded i.e. http://abc.example.com/jsptest.jsp It is showing plain text as under:

> Test JSP page
>
> ## Sample Application JSP Page
>
> This is
>   the output of a JSP page that is part of the Hello, World application.
>   It displays several useful values from the requestwe are currently
>   processing.  
>   Request Method: <%=
>   request.getMethod() %> Servlet
>   Path: <%= request.getServletPath()
>   %>

I have done following entries in sftp://root@example.com/usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/conf/server.xml

```
<Host name="abc.example.com" appBase="/home/example96/public_html/abc">
          <Alias>www.abc.example.com</Alias> 
          <Context path="" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/example96/public_html/abc" debug="1"/>
          <Context path="/manager" debug="0" privileged="true"
              docBase="/usr/local/jakarta/tomcat/server/webapps/manager">
          </Context>
       </Host>
```

Please note jsp/java on my other subdomains are working fine on same server/domain.

Comment: where is your jsp located ?

Comment: http://abc.example.com/jsptest.jsp

Comment: file physical location ? I think your application is in tomcat and your appbase must point to /usr/local/jakarta/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/webapps

Comment: It is hosted on linux server (VPS) home/example96/public_html/abc/

Comment: My other subdomains are working same way. Kindly suggest changes.

Comment: is your jsp located at /home/example96/public_html/abc/ ?

Comment: yes!!! home/example96/public_html/abc/

Comment: use  `<Context path="/" reloadable="true" docBase="/home/example96/public_html/abc" debug="1"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked and noticed other subdomains they had a htaccess with the following text in them:

```
SetHandler jakarta-servlet
SetEnv JK_WORKER_NAME ajp13
```

jsp files working now.